# Add Label to Variant Selector (Shopify)

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I have a dropdown with my product variants (title Color). I would like to add a label to that dropdown ("Select Color"). I see that Shopify adds a label when theres more than one Variant, but I cant find the code that allows me to update that.

Im using the theme Simple.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you'll find this code snippets in assets > theme.js.liquid in simple theme.

```
/**
 *
 *  Adjust option_selection.js labels based on variant default values
 *
 */
Slate.simplifyVariantLabels = function (product) {
  // option_selection.js does not add a label if there is only one variant option.
  // Add one as long as it is not 'Title' (Shopify's default), add one.
  if (product.options.length === 1 && product.options[0] !== 'Title') {
    $('.selector-wrapper:eq(0)').prepend('<label for="ProductSelect-option-0">'+ product.options[0] +'</label>');
  }

  // Hide variant dropdown if only one exists and title contains 'Default'
  if (product.variants.length && product.variants[0].title.indexOf('Default') >= 0) {
    $('.selector-wrapper').hide();
  }
};
```